# How can I save address of user to some central server?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app of iphone, the main feature of app is to purchase hard goods using paypal, I am a bit confused that how can user send address of his home to server or company for delivering the product.

It is a bit hard for me because this is first time I am making such app, just one query that how can I send my data to company, so that it can deliver product to me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.company.com/send.php?arcticle=%i&address=%@", articleNumber, address]]
                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:60.0];
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Connection succeeded
} else {
    // Connection failed
}
```

Comment: but I want to develop the app, so what is suitable way to send the address of home?

Comment: and there will be 50 user taking 50 different goods, so how to inform company about their address ?

Comment: You cannot send the address unless the company gives you the permission.

Comment: I have the complete authority of server, so now can you provide a few lines of code for sending establishing connection and sending address to server

Comment: Ok, you will need to add a PHP file which receives the informations.